# Show that for symmetric matrices, $A_n \rightarrow A$ if and only if $l'A_n l \rightarrow l'Al$ for any vector $l$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

In an article I read the following assertion: *a sequence of symmetric matrices $\{A_n\}$ converges to a symmetric matrix $A$ if and only if $l'A_nl \rightarrow l'Al$ for all comfortable vectors $l$.* (I don't know what the authors mean by "comfortable vector", but I suppose it's irrelevant).

Now if we know $A_n$ converges, it follows easily the convergence of $l'A_nl$. But I have been wondering how to prove the converse is true. It seems to me symmetry here is critical, but I have no idea how to exploit it (maybe such property can be generalized to any *compact symmetric operator* on a Hilbert space?)

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean conformable, not comfortable.

Comment: Conformable just means "of the appropriate size for matrix multiplication"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this property can be generalized to Hilbert spaces.

There are a few ways to look at this, but the most straightforward is in terms of the matrix entries.  Certainly, if $A_n(i,j) \to A(i,j)$ for all $i,j$, then we're done.  To prove that this is the case, it suffices to make some clever choices for $l$.

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis (i.e. the columns of the identity matrix). Taking $l = e_i$, we see that $l'A_nl = A_n(i,i)$, which means that our statement holds for the diagonal entries.  If we then take $l = e_i + e_j$ (with $i \neq j$), we see that
$$
l'A_nl = (e_i + e_j)^T A_n (e_i + e_j) = A_n(i,i) + A_n(i,j) + A_n(j,i) + A_n(j,j)
$$
So, we see that
$$
A_n(i,i) + 2A_n(i,j) + A_n(j,j) \to A(i,i) + 2A(i,j) + A(j,j) 
$$
We already know, however, that $A_n(i,i) \to A(i,i)$ and that $A_n(j,j) \to A(j,j) $.  We can therefore conclude that $A_n(i,j) \to A(i,j)$ when $i \neq j$.

Thus, we see that $A_n \to A$, as desired.

Comment: thanks for the hint! The proof is simple on finite dimensional space. However, I am wondering how the same argument can be generalized to a Hilbert space. Following the same line we are able to show $\langle e_i, A_n e_j\rangle \rightarrow \langle e_i, A e_j \rangle$ for a orthonormal base $\{e_i\}$. But what should be the next step? I mean how to argue, when limit is involved, that $\langle x, A_n y \rangle$ tends to $\langle x, A y \rangle$. And, even if I suppose this to be true, I only know Riesz representation theorem can be applied to show weak convergence, instead of $A_n$

Comment: I just figured out how to prove it in general:-) and thanks for the answer!